# Create new vendor application for YII2 in GitHub

Tags: github, composer-php, yii2

I created a very simple plugin for yii2 and added it to Github.

https://github.com/harlangray/languageswitcher

When I add "harlangray/languageswitcher": "*" to the require section and run composer update on my project, it gives me an error.

Problem 1
  - The requested package xxxxx could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https:xxxxx for more details.

Read http:yyyyy for further common problems.

I am really new to github and composer. Can someone give me the steps to create a plugin and make it uninstallable via composer?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer has no idea about github packages, unless you add them as under the `repositories` as a `package`.

If you want to be able to install it via the `require` section you'll need to add your package to [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). This is the site composers gets the package meta information from.

Only thing you have to do is register, click the big "Submit Package" button and point it to your github project. Optionally (but advised) you could setup a hook in github to update packagist every time you commit something to github so that you don't have to do it manually.